# How to send file from my telegram bot (node.js)

Tags: node.js, file, bots, telegram

I am trying to create a telegram bot that downloads an mp3 file from a youtube video link.

I'm using telegram npm package and youtube-mp3-downloader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-mp3-downloader) to do so.

For now, when I forward a youtube video link to my bot, it download it as expected but, I can't find a way to send this via the bot. It just saves it locally.

I've read about file_id but cant find none since I didn't upload anything. Is there an actual way to send an mp3 file locally saved via my bot?

Comment: https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=working-with-files i would give `ctx.replyWithDocument({
    source: 'path/to/audio.mp3'
  });` a try.

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks. I ve tried something with replywithdocument but it didnt work. Now it is and i know why.